# Alternatives for storing a class member as a raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, polymorphism, smart-pointers

In the code example shown below - in `Container` class, it **owns** (and is responsible fore destroying) two objects `c, d`, which are subclasses of an abstract class `B`. `Container` object can create new `ObjectDisplay` that takes a kind of B in its constructor. I can pass the abstract type B as a pointer into `ObjectDisplay` and store it as a **RAW pointer**. But it's not ideal to store & use a raw pointer and always check if it's a null pointer. If B wasn't an abstract class, I could pass it in `ObjectDisplay` as a reference (ie. `ObjectDisplay (B& b)`). But since I can't change B, I wonder what's the aternative of storing B* object as a raw pointer in `ObjectDisplay`?

```
// B is abstract
class B
{
public:
    virtual int getDefault() = 0;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    int getDefault() override { return 1; }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    int getDefault() override { return 5; }
};

class ObjectDisplay
{
public:
ObjectDisplay (B* b) : object (b) {}

void someFunction()
{
    const auto result = b->getDefault();
    // do something
}

private:
B* object;
};

class Container
{
public:
    void addDisplay()
    {
    displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (&c));
    displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (&d));    
    }
private:
    C c;
    D d;
    std::vector<ObjectDisplay> displays;
};
```

Comment: Does `ObjectDisplay` 'own' `object` (i.e. is it responsible for destroying it when it's no longer needed)?  If not, who does own it?  And when I say 'own', I'm talking about the object pointed to, of course.

Comment: @PaulSanders `Container` owns `object` and is responsible for destroying it.

Comment: FYI: you don't have to always check if it's a null pointer, if you know it isn't one.

Comment: Raw pointers are the usual way to do this. People say "never use raw pointers" too much, when they actually mean "never use raw pointers for ownership because unique_ptr is much easier"

Comment: Nothing describes the intended ownership as well as a raw pointer. `std::unique_ptr` with a custom do-nothing deleter does what you want, but does it in a round-about manner and this sends the wrong message, that the `unique_ptr` owns the object, to casual readers of the code. Confuse people and bugs will ensue.

Comment: @Thinium Sorry, it was a dumb question, I see it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If B wasn't an abstract class, I could pass it in ObjectDisplay as a reference

No, if `B` is an abstract class, you can still pass it by reference. `B& object` can be bound to an instance of `B`'s subclass. It behaves almost the same as pointers.

As quoted in [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> That is to say, if a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class, a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior defined in the derived class.

Declare a member of `B&` in `ObjectDisplay` and construct it through a reference.

```cpp
class ObjectDisplay
{
public:
    ObjectDisplay (B& b) : object (b) {}
private:
    B& object;

};

class Container
{
public:
    void addDisplay()
    {
        displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (c));
        displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (d));    
    }
};
```

See online [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjGT9z96T)

Aside:
Since you are passing a temporary `ObjectDisplay` object directly constructed in `push_back`, I recommend you to use `emplace_back`.

```cpp
    void addDisplay()
    {
        displays.emplace_back (c);
        displays.emplace_back (d);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If `B` wasn't an abstract class, I could pass it in `ObjectDisplay` as a reference (ie. `ObjectDisplay (B& b)`). But since I can't change `B`, I wonder what's the aternative of storing `B* object` as a raw pointer in `ObjectDisplay`?

Just because `B` is an abstract class does not mean you are required to pass it around and store it as a *pointer*.  You CAN pass it around and store it as a *reference* as well. Polymorphism works with pointers AND references. And using a reference would indeed solve your `nullptr` issue, eg:

```
class ObjectDisplay
{
public:
    ObjectDisplay (B& b) : object (b) {}

    void someFunction()
    {
        const auto result = object.getDefault();
        // do something
    }

private:
    B& object;
};

class Container
{
public:
    void addDisplay()
    {
        displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (c));
        displays.push_back (ObjectDisplay (d));    
    }

private:
    C c;
    D d;
    std::vector<ObjectDisplay> displays;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HeDqEZ)

As long as `c` and `d` outlive the `ObjectDisplay` objects in `displays`, you will be just fine, whether you use pointers or references.